# Trigger on EmailMessage to update related Case is actually creating new case

Tags: trigger, case, email2case, emailmessage

**Below is what I am trying to do** -

1. migrating users from one org to another
2. as a part of this "email to case" will be migrated as well
3. open cases from "old org" will be migrated to "new org" with 
   case id from old org saved as "external id" field on new org case object
4. After the migration, if customer replies to the email that corresponds to open case and has thread id (ref:_00Dxxxxx._500xxxxxxxx:ref) from the old org, i need to associate such email messages to corresponding migrated case in the new org

I have before insert trigger on EmailMessage which is looking for incoming emails and associating these emailmessage to existing case in the new org.
Within the trigger, I am updating "ParentId" and "ReleatedToId" field on EmailMessage, if incoming email thread id is from old org.

**Actual Result:**

I see that email message is correctly being related to existing case BUT I also see
a new case created.
When Before insert trigger hits, I already see "ParentId" and "RelatedToId" field on the EmailMessage populated
with newly created case id, before I update these IDs in my trigger code

Why salesforce is creating new case ?  is it possible to prevent creating of new case ?

Below is the code as requested, below is my trigger handler on EmailMessage

```
public class EmailMessageTriggerHandler {

 public static void handle(List<EmailMessage> newEmailMessageList,
                          Map<Id, EmailMessage> newEmailMessageMap,
                          List<EmailMessage> oldEmailMessageList,
                          Map<Id, EmailMessage> oldEmailMessageMap,
                          Boolean isBefore,
                          Boolean isAfter,
                          Boolean isInsert,
                          Boolean isUpdate,                              
                          Boolean isDelete)
 {         
     if(isBefore)
     {
         if(isInsert)
         {
             for(EmailMessage msg: newEmailMessageList)
             {
                //at this point for incoming emailmessage with thread id not associated with org in which trigger is running,
                // parent id and relatedtoId is already populated with Id of the newly created case
                 system.debug('msg is incoming - ' + msg.Incoming);
                 system.debug('msg thread id - ' + msg.ThreadIdentifier);
                 system.debug('msg status - ' + msg.Status);
                 system.debug('msg subject - ' + msg.Subject);
                 system.debug('msg parent id - ' + msg.ParentId);
                 system.debug('msg related to id - ' + msg.RelatedToId);
                 system.debug('msg body - ' + msg.TextBody);

             }
             ProcessMessageForOldCases(newEmailMessageList, newEmailMessageMap);
         }             
     }

 }

public static void ProcessMessageForOldCases(List<EmailMessage> newEmailMessageList, Map<Id, EmailMessage> newEmailMessageMap)
{
    Map<Id, String> oldCaseMessageToThreadMap = new Map<Id, String>();

    RecordType rt = [SELECT Id,DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType='Case' AND DeveloperName='My_Record_type' LIMIT 1];

    //Legacy_Case_Id__c is external id - containts 15 digit case id from old org
    //

    List<Case> oldCases = [select Id, Legacy_Case_Id_Short__c from Case where RecordTypeId =:rt.Id AND Legacy_Case_Id__c LIKE '500%'];



    for(EmailMessage msg: newEmailMessageList)
    {            
        if(msg.Incoming)
        {
            //get thread id
            string emailthreadid = getThreadId(msg.Subject);                
            try
            {
                if(String.isNotBlank(emailthreadid))
                {
                    //check if email message thread is from this org and case from this org
                    Id caseid = Cases.getCaseIdFromEmailThreadId(emailthreadid);                        
                }                                        
            }
            catch(Exception exp)
            {
                system.debug('exception');
                //if exception, incoming email contains thread id that corresponds to old org

                string oldcaseshortidfromEmail = '';

                string[] parts = emailthreadid.split('._');
                if(parts != null && parts.size() > 1)
                {
                    if(String.isNotBlank(parts[parts.size() - 1]) )
                    {
                        oldcaseshortidfromEmail = parts[parts.size() - 1];
                    }
                }

                //find it in existing cases
                for(Case oldcase: oldCases)
                {
                    //do case sensitive comparison
                    //Legacy_Case_Id_Short__c is formula field which converts 15 digit Legacy_Case_Id__c to format that is in thread id - 500xxxxxxxx
                    String oldcaseshortid = oldcase.Legacy_Case_Id_Short__c;                        
                    if(oldcaseshortid.equals(oldcaseshortidfromEmail))
                    {
                        system.debug('match found');                            
                        //associate to new case
                        system.debug('updating case association');
                        system.debug('new id = ' + oldcase.Id);
                        msg.ParentId = oldcase.Id;    
                        msg.RelatedToId = oldcase.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        system.debug('no match found');
                    }
                }


            } //end of catch

        }//end of if
    }//end of for                

}

public static String getThreadId(String subject)
{
    //return string is in format - _00Dxxxxx._500xxxxxxxx

    String[] parts = subject.split('ref:');
    if(parts!= null)
    {
        //get the last string
        if(parts[parts.size() - 1] != null)
        {
            string[] moreparts = parts[parts.size() - 1].split(':ref');
            if(moreparts != null && String.isNotBlank(moreparts[0]))
            {
                return moreparts[0];
            }
        }

    }
    return '';
}
```

}

Comment: @SantanuBoral , in my case, incoming email already has thread id in subject and body but that thread id belongs to old org and doesn't belong to org where this trigger is executing. Within the trigger, I am trying to associate it to existing case

Comment: I think, because of old org, salesforce is creating new cases. Salesforce tries to attach the replies into same cases if matching threadId is found. You can try creating InboundEmailHandler to attach the email in same case

Comment: You've not shown your code, but it sounds as though you need to be doing an update to the related case or some kind of upsert operation rather than just an insert operation on the email. Would help immensely if you posted code. Also, since you're specifying a ParentId, that' would seem to be a likely cause of creation of new case.

Comment: @crmprogdev only updating parentld will not solve the issue. Salesforce internally maps through Email header information I think.

Comment: @SantanuBoral More than anything, it would seem he may need to start with the related case is where I was coming from and updating it with the new email attachment, but that's speculation on my part. Is difficult when you migrate data from one org to another.

Comment: @crmprogdev I have added the code as requested. Thanks!

Comment: I think the issue is that E2C creates a Case long before it inserts EmailMessage. You'll need to delete the new case in addition to reparenting the EmailMessage

Comment: @cropredy, i tried to run the same logic on before insert trigger of Case instead of EmailMessage, but anytime an email comes in with ref ids corresponding to different org, salesforce is striping of these ref ids from subject and body and creating new case. Case Trigger doesn't see these old ref ids when I inspect case subject and description

Comment: @cropredy, I have an case notification email that goes out, so even if I can delete the case, an email notification might have already gone out

Comment: I believe you can reverse engineer the refId to detect the old org and thus prevent sending out emails if you use workflows in lieu of case Settings